# Reinstall Windows 10 in virtualbox cannot activate

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, virtualbox, windows-10

right now I have a windows10-linux dual-boot system on my laptop. I rarely use windows but sometimes it is necessary. I installed windows10 in virtualbox but cannot activate it with the same product key, -makes sense.

My question is, if I deinstall the system on the real-machine, can I activate windows10 then on virtualbox? I used to reinstalled windows10 on the same machine, there was no problem. How could the server know, whether the key/system is activated or uninstalled?

Thanks

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

If Windows is preinstalled by the OEM, then the license (product key) is tied to that motherboard. An OEM license cannot be moved to a different motherboard, nor to a Virtual Machine.

If you purchased the Windows license directly from Microsoft, then you can move it to any machine or VM you wish.

The most common scenario for most folks is that their pre-installed Windows has an OEM license, so it cannot be moved to a VM.